# Update one table from another table while sorting that table based on one column

Tags: mysql, update, order-by

This is the problem I'm trying to figure out in MySQL. We have an old table contains some forms submitted by our users. Somehow, the previous decision was each time a user comes to this survey, a new form will be submitted. So in the old table we easily have several rows with the same Firstname, Lastname, but different values in the other columns, and there's a timestamp column Date_Submission as well.

Now we are trying to move everything to a new table, but this time, for each person we only keep one row. And we want to keep some of the the latest old data of that user (like email, phone number, etc)

I could do the following:

> update newtable, oldtable set newtable.email = oldtable.email where newtable.firstname = oldtable.firstname and newtable.lastname = oldtable.lastname;

Apparently this won't give me the "latest" old date for each person.

So I tried this one:

> update newtable, oldtable set newtable.email = oldtable.email where newtable.firstname = oldtable.firstname and newtable.lastname = oldtable.lastname order by oldtable.Date_Submission;

But they MySQL will complain with:

> "ERROR 1221 (HY000): Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY".

So I'm wondering, what's the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

There are two options:

1. [INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

   ```
   INSERT INTO newtable
   SELECT * FROM oldtable
   ORDER BY tmstamp_value
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE email=VALUES(email), address=VALUES(address) 
   ... ;
   ```
2. [REPLACE INTO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html)

   ```
   REPLACE INTO newtable
   SELECT * FROM oldtable
   ORDER BY tmstamp_value;
   ```

   It mechanically performs a DELETE and an INSERT.

**CAVEAT**

Notice I applied the `ORDER BY` against the old table. This should help get the latest data for a given LastName, FirstName.

You should also add a `UNIQUE INDEX` on the new table as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE newtable ADD UNIQUE INDEX name_ndx (lastname,firstname);
```

---

If you are doing updates, there are two ways to do this:

1. UPDATE JOIN

   ```
   UPDATE
   (SELECT lastname,firstname,phone,email
   FROM oldtable ORDER BY lastname,firstname) A
   LEFT JOIN newtable B USING (lastname,firstname)
   SET B.phone=A.phone,B.email=A.email;
   ```
2. UPDATE JOIN with GROUP BY

   ```
   UPDATE
   (
       SELECT BB.id,BB.phone,BB.email FROM 
       (SELECT lastname,firstname,MAX(id) id FROM oldtable GROUP BY lastname,firstname) AA
       INNER JOIN oldtable BB USING (lastname,firstname)
   ) A INNER JOIN newtable B USING (id)
   SET B.phone=A.phone,B.email=A.email;
   ```

Both options will take full advantage of the `UNIQUE` index on name.