# Mysql REPLACE INTO query for Multiple rows insertion

Tags: mysql, trigger, replace

I'm trying to add multiple rows using 'replace into' , but its updating one row.

```
REPLACE INTO user_balance
(user_id,acc_type,currency,balance,enable_deposit,
enable_withdrawal,pending_balance,update_ip)  
VALUES  (NEW.id,1,'USD',0,1,0,0,NEW.ip_address),
(NEW.id,1,'GBP',0,1,0,0,NEW.ip_address),
(NEW.id,1,'EUR',0,1,0,0,NEW.ip_address),
(NEW.id,1,'BTC',0,1,0,0,NEW.ip_address);
```

Is this right, the way am doing it?

PS: am employing a trigger to update the balance table whenever an user is created in the users table. It works well with if I replace one row, for multiple rows, it updates only the last values.

Answer (score 4):

You should avoid using triggers in conjunction with `REPLACE INTO` on multiple rows. Why ?

`REPLACE INTO` is nothing more than a mechanical `DELETE` and `INSERT`. It can incite mysqld to address deadlocks (See my answer to [How I prevent deadlock occurrence in my application?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36481/how-i-prevent-deadlock-occurrence-in-my-application/36515#36515))

Here are two comments that shows [the LIFO approach to processing triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html)

> Posted by Atif Ghaffar on September 23 2007 9:12pm    [Delete] [Edit]
>   PLEASE Note that the REPLACE does a DELETE operation.
>
> We did not realize this and had the triggers that should be triggered
>   on DELETE triggered.
>
> After checking all the code, we just found a script that does a
>   replace to refresh the values of some fields.
>
> We should have had used "insert into ... on duplicate update" syntax
>   instead.
>
> Posted by J Mike on May 4 2009 11:06pm    [Delete] [Edit] If you are
>   using REPLACE INTO... triggers are fired in this order (if delete of
>   duplcate key is used):
>
> - before insert
> - before delete
> - after delete
> - after insert

Your problem ? An UPDATE trigger will never fire off if this has to be done multiple times in a single operation. At least, I don't see that happening.

## SUGGESTIONS

- You may want to use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` (See my answer to [Update one table from another table while sorting that table based on one column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39531/update-one-table-from-another-table-while-sorting-that-table-based-on-one-column/39532#39532))
- Stick to doing `REPLACE` on one row at a time